# Is sharing the same database between two programming languages possible?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework

Program A is good at collecting data while Program B, in another language, is good at creating REST APIs. Is it possible to connect these two with a single database that A and B will read and write to? Performance for database operations is not really an issue in my case.

Comment: Of course.  Have you *tried*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this is possible. Databases typically can handle multiple connections from different programs/clients. A database does not really care which language the tool that is making the connection is written in.

Short edit:
Also most databases support "transactions". Which are used to cover that different connected clients do not break consistency of your application data while reading and writing in parallel.